# Is using jQuery.html() a vulnerability when I control the result

Tags: c#, jquery, xss

So basically I have an ajax call which hits a method which returns a partial view and to display the data I use jQuery.html().

We are running our code through a veracode security tool and it's raising a XSS vulnerability.

Here is the jquery:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "ReturnTransNoInformation",
            data: { __RequestVerificationToken: ReturnAntiForgeryToken(), TransNo: $("[data-trans-no]").val() },
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function () {
                TransNoInfoAjaxBegin("[data-view-trans-no-container]");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success === false) {
                    if (data.ErrorMessage !== undefined && data.ErrorMessage !== null && data.ErrorMessage !== "") {
                        Error(data.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                    else {
                        Error("Something went wrong while loading the TransNo info, please refresh the page and try again.")
                    }
                    $("[data-transno-partial]").html(null); //Potential XSS
                }
                else {
                    $("[data-transno-partial]").html(data); //Potential XSS
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                Error("Something went wrong while loading the TransNo info, please refresh the page and try again.")
            },
            complete: function () {
                AjaxComplete("[data-view-trans-no-container]");
            }
        });
```

My C# code:

```
        [AuthorizeUsers(new UserLevel[] { UserLevel.SubRepMaster, UserLevel.Regional })]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ReturnTransNoInformation(string transNo) {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(transNo)) return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "Error: TransNo cannot be empty" });

            var info = await _iAccountingManager.ReturnTransNoInfoAsync(transNo, SessionInfo.CIDs);

            if (info == null) return Json(new { Success = false, ErrorMessage = "Error: TransNo does not exist" });

            return PartialView("~/Views/Accounting/Partials/_TransNoInfo.cshtml", new TransNoInfoViewModel(info));
        }
```

My partial view is entirely controller by me with no JS in the partial view. Is this an actual XSS vulnerability?

Comment: Is it just saying the page is a XSS vulnerability or a specific line?

Comment: Specific line, I marked the line with "Potential XSS"

Comment: Would only be open to XSS if the server side html content was generated with user input content that wasn't sanitized

Comment: @charlietfl Thought so, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are under control of the code being displayed, then no.
XSS relies on a malicious third party inputting code into your website.

If there are no third parties which can change the input to their desired input, then there is no problem with XSS on your site.